# problems with my socket thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking

I've been having alot of trouble since I started playing with sockets, I have managed to do basic tasks which I have learnt from tutorials online and with help of the community, but I have realised that I now need to use threads which has added another layer of complications. Below is my thread which I have modified for my needs, but it doesn;t do as intended. I have marked in the code how far the program runs but it stops at the important bit. Could someone take a look and tell me why my program stops here? Thanks in advance.

```
public void run() {
try {
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

    /// RUNS THIS FAR
    String score = (in.readLine());
    scor = Long.parseLong(score);
        leaderboard(); // A METHOD THAT TAKES LONG SCORE, CALCULATES RANKING AND RETURNS A STRING CALLED RANK


        System.out.print("Sending rank: " + rank);
        out.println(rank);
}
catch(IOException e) {
    System.out.println("PrintWriter error");
}

//out.println("Hello");

try {
    socket.close();
}
    catch(IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Failed to close, oddly...");
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how far the program runs"? In case an exception is thrown, you should use `e.printStackTrace();` and post the exception generated.

Comment: I mean code thats under my marking doesn't execute. Ive not actually come across that phrase yet... I assume the stack is the order of tasks to do. What does the trace() part mean?  Sorry im new to sockets and struggling to understand. Is this printStackTrace() a subject thats essential to go and learn? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, stack trace is an essential subject to learn.

Comment: I have already started reading an article. Thanks.

Comment: I have had a little play around now. Its a numberFormatException - at java.lang.Long.parseLong(unknown Source).  It looks like when I convert string score to long scor, it doesn't recognise string score. Thats what it seems like.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a little playing about, it appears that by putting the String in question into its own try/catch block has solved the issue. All is working sweetly. Thanks anyhow guys, printStackTrace() has also taught me a little more.

Comment: This answer explains nothing and nether does your question.

Comment: I still dont understand why using a try/ catch block has worked, but like magic it has. Sorry for your misinterpretation of the question, I was simply asking why my code didnt run fully(not read input). As for my answering of the question, this was only done to save peoples time on other peoples questions, my problem is solved, the least I can do is  learn for my self why it works, instead of relying on you guys doing my work